# Multidimensional array from query into string gives Array to string conversion notice

Tags: php, xml, string, curl, multidimensional-array

I'm using CURL to pass an xml string created from the results of a query.

The string is created as follows:

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($data_to_insert)) {$data[ ] = $row;}

foreach($data as $datapiece)
{
 $data = data.'
 <field>
 <id>'.$datapiece["id"].'</id>
 <value>'.$datapiece["value"].'</value>
```

Why am I getting Array to string conversion notice?

Comment: Show all of your code related to this and which line the error comes up on.

Comment: I'm talking about in the while loop and after. You need to say which line is giving the error.

Comment: Before the while loop there are only DB credentials, the error is on the line inside the foreach loop  on <id>'.$datapiece["id"].'</id>, after the while loop I have a $header variable that I insert into the xml to be sent as follows: $xml = $header.$string  A var dump for $array shows the following: string(85) "Array 1 2 "

Comment: Exactly the same as:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12959196/array-to-string-conversion-error-in-php

Comment: What is `$string` ? And could `print_r($datapiece);` please.

Comment: I made a mistake on the pasted code... Sorry actually I was treating $string as $array so they were the same variable.

Comment: I updated the code instead of $array and $string there is only $data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($data_to_insert)) {$data[ ] = $row;} --->    $data is array in here

foreach($data as $datapiece)
{
$data = data.' ----> data is a string in here IT SHOULDN'T BE OVERWRITING PREVIOUS VARIABLE, VARIABLE NEEDS TO BE GIVEN A DIFFERNT NAME
<field>
<id>'.$datapiece["id"].'</id>
<value>'.$datapiece["value"].'</value>
```

Comment: Why did you post this as an answer?.. And why are you overwriting the `$data` variable?

Comment: That was the mistake. I shouldn't have been overwriting $data. The $data = $data. '.... should have a different name. And that solves the problem. I really appreciate you taking the time to help me. It is the same situation as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12959196/array-to-string-conversion-error-in-php